# What Unicode character is the key symbol shown by the macOS SSH command?

Tags: macos, ssh, unicode

[image: macOS SSH key symbol]

I'm writing a console app that requests a password and I'd like to use the same symbol as the macOS `ssh` command, but it doesn't show up in the Character Viewer (⌘⌃Space) under the word KEY.  The closest is or . Seems to be Mac specific as I don't see it in the source code for [OpenSSH](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable). Anyone know to produce this symbol?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a character, it's the insertion point (the text cursor), and it's drawn by the terminal app, not ssh. It looks like you're using iTerm; if you run this in Terminal, you'll see that it displays a different icon. The key icon you're looking for is in iTerm's Resources folder (key.tiff).

The key cursor gets enabled whenever ECHO is turned off on the terminal. For example, in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (){
    struct termios termInfo, save;

    // Fetch the current attributes
    if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &termInfo) == -1) {
        perror("tcgetattr");
        exit(1);
    }

    save = termInfo;

    // turn off ECHO, and ECHONL on
    termInfo.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    termInfo.c_lflag |= ECHONL; // echo newline even if echo is off

    // Set it
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSASOFT|TCSADRAIN, &termInfo);

    printf("Password: ");

    // Consume characters until the user presses enter
    while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n') {}
    printf("Accepted\n");

    // Set it back to the original values
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSASOFT|TCSADRAIN, &save);
}
```

This will display the key icon you're looking for.